# Will setTimeOut function in recursive function cause stack overflow?

Tags: jquery

Does the following function cause stack overthrow eventually?

```
var isFinish= false;  
function foo(){         
// ajax call       
//in ajax success   
success: function(response){
setTimeout(function(){ 
     if (!isFinish)
     {            
       foo();   
     }    
     },1000);    
    }   
 }
```

Comment: Are you experiencing an issue? I remember seeing another user's question that was similar where there was a memory issue. It seemed to be related to `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't. `setTimeout` is asynchronous (presumably as is your AJAX request), so `foo` is able to exit immediately.

If jQuery has memory leaks in its `$.ajax`, then that's another issue.

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with calling `foo()` again from `setTimeout()`.  This is NOT actually recursion because the first invocation of `foo()` has actually finished executing before the second invocation starts on the `setTimeout()`.

So, there is no buildup of the stack at all.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I have not had an issue with this type of function.  I would feel comfortable using this code on my server and application.