# Is there will be any stack overflow error with setTimeout() in 1st function and closure 2nd function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout, stack-overflow, nested-loops

Is it possible that here will be stack overflow error after some time of work (after few hours of calculations)?
Or another errors in long run here?

```
    var timerIdPrecalculationsTurns = null;

    function precalculationsInit() {
        if (!timerIdPrecalculationsTurns) {
            timerIdPrecalculationsTurns = setTimeout(function(){
                precalculationsInitClosure();
            }, 10);
        }
    }

    function precalculationsInitClosure() {
        // make some calculations for ~20ms ...
        // and then repeat in next iteration:
        timerIdPrecalculationsTurns = null;
        precalculationsInit();
    }

    // just start the loop
    precalculationsInit();
```

It is simplified version of code, I used. But it will tell about my problem, I hope.

There are some similar answers, but I am not sure if it is my situation also:

[Will setTimeOut function in recursive function cause stack overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829366/will-settimeout-function-in-recursive-function-cause-stack-overflow)

[JavaScript Closures and setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479604/javascript-closures-and-settimeout)

Comment: Yes, those answers apply to your code as well. Why do you think it's different? That the timeout is created in a "subroutine" (`precalculationsInit`) of the function `precalculationsInitClosure` that is called from (the function expression that is called by) the timeout doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there won't be.

Timers "set aside" the callback - they don't call them in the same execution stack as the one that's currently running (the one calling `setTimeout`). JS will continue executing the current script until the stack is empty before calling any callback set by a timer (or any completed async operation for that matter).

In your case `precalculationsInit` would "schedule" `precalculationsInitClosure`, then finish executing, emptying the stack. Then at least 10ms later, JS would call the scheduled `precalculationsInitClosure`, do stuff, then call `precalculationsInit` and repeats the same procedure.

Your stack would look like:

```
(empty)
pI (schedules pIC)
(empty, JS looks for callbacks)
pIC
pIC -> pI (schedules pIC)
pIC
(empty, JS looks for callbacks)
pIC
pIC -> pI (schedules pIC)
pIC
(empty)
...and so on
```

As you can see, because of this "scheduling"/"setting aside", the stack does not build up like in recursion:

```
pI
pI -> pIC
pI -> pIC -> pI
pI -> pIC -> pI -> pIC
...and so on
```

Comment: Thank you. It is very usefull explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any issue with the way you implemented this. I would recommend for you to use **setInterval** instead for this use case.

Comment: If there's no issue, why are you recommending something else? :-P

Comment: @Bergi Cleaner and more readable

Comment: Thanks, but my periodical work have different time execution: 10ms - 150ms. So intervals not best in my case.